# To print a document in SAP Business One

Tags: c#, sdk, sapb1

I am updating my programming skills and moving from vb.net to C# and one pf the first projects I want to work on is making a SAP addin that will print documents from a list or grid.

Comment: What is the actual question? If it's "how do I print a document" there's a report renderer in newer versions of Service Layer.

Comment: I want to print a physical invoice and not sure where that would be in the SDK.